# springboot throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError but standalone java applicaton works fine

Tags: java, dll

I have a standalone java application that uses a dll and jar file to encrypt and decrypt strings.  I am loading the dll using system.loadlibrary("dllfile with extension"). It is working fine.

I am trying to call the same application from Springboot by submitting the values from a form. I can see the form data. but the when the java application method is called, it thrown the  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.pack.pack.Class.MethodName()I error.  I have the dll and jar file configured in the path and classpath.

I am using eclipse IDE on windows 64 bit

What might be the issue ?

Standalone java app => works fine.

```
        import com.pack.library.*;

       public class Stand
       {
    static {
    System.loadLibrary("somedll");
   }

   public static void main(String a[])
   {
    Stand s = new Stand();
    s.doEnc("Test String");
   }

   public void doEnc(String inStr)
   {
    EncVal ev = new EncVal()
    System.out.println(ev.getEncryptedValue(inStr));
       }        

   public Stand()
   {
   }    
    }
```

---

```
   Springboot ==> fails with exception


   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
     import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

   @SpringBootApplication
     public class OpaqueApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(OpaqueApplication.class, args);       
}   
    }
```

---

```
      import sprinbootstuff;
      import com.pack.library.*;

      @Controller
      public class ToolSetController {

      @RequestMapping("/enc-dec-process-form")
      public ModelAndView encDecProcessForm(@Valid Toolset toolset, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        Stand aess = new Stand();
        String encryptedText = aess.doEnc(toolset.getTextToProcess());
        toolset.setTextareaField(encryptedText);
        mav.addObject(toolset);
        mav.setViewName("home");
        return mav;
    }
```

2018-10-05 10:55:21.371 ERROR 31336 --- [io-10081-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.pack.library.Const.DIGEST_MD5()I] with root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.pack.library.Const.DIGEST_MD5()I

Comment: what is that you want to do exactly

Comment: call a java class that uses dll from springboot...but its failing with unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: its working now.

Comment: @user6400807 Hi, how do you fix this problem? I have the same question.

Comment: @user6400807 how is it fixed